# How to access object's properties from a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using DisplayNameFor for my table's header text but I encountered this error where I can't access the object's properties from my model. I'm new to web programming so any help, advice and suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Models used:

```
public class DashboardModel
{
    public List<BarangayModel> BrgyModel { get; set; }
    public PersonStatusModel PerStatusModel { get; set; }
}
public class BarangayModel
{
    public string Barangay { get; set; }
    public int Confirmed { get; set; }
    public int PUI { get; set; }
    public int PUM { get; set; }
}
public class PersonStatusModel
{
    public int TotalConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int TotalPUI { get; set; }
    public int TotalPUM { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 @model LearningAsp.Models.DashboardModel
 -----
 <h1 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => Model.PerStatusModel.TotalConfirmed)</h1>
 -----
 <th style="text-align:center;"> 
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BrgyModel.Barangay)
 </th>
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRq5v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `BrgyModel` in `Dashboard` is List, you can access property by index, example as

```
 <th style="text-align:center;"> 
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BrgyModel[0].Barangay)
 </th>
```

Or you can use `foreach` to display all `BrgyModel` item

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion! 